# Making a function upperBits

Tags: bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift

I am supposed to make a function that does this: (the code in the function is what i've got so far!)

```
 * upperBits - pads n upper bits with 1's
 *  You may assume 0 <= n <= 32
 *  Example: upperBits(4) = 0xF0000000
 *  Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
 *  Max ops: 10
 *  Rating: 1
 */
int upperBits(int n) {

   int x;
   x = (x << n) - 1;
    return (x << (32-n));
}
```

The function works every time except when the input is `0` (`upperBits(0)`) then the output is `0xffffffff` when it should be `0`. Don't know how to do this.

Comment: You could just insert `if (n == 0) return 0;` after `int x;`

Comment: I am not allowed to use if-statements only bit-wise operators.

Comment: You need to repair what you have first. It certainly can't be good when `x` has been locally declared, uninitialized, and you are using it in the expression, `(x << n) - 1`. Perhaps `x` happens to default to `0` for you in these cases, but it's definitely a problem. Your problem does highlight an interesting behavior in C in which `0xFFFFFFFF << 32` results in `0xFFFFFFFF` (a `<< 32` is ignored).

Comment: I was thinking the same thing yesterday about the x.. but somehow it always got the right output except for the 0. But now i've noticed another problem. And that is that I am not allowed to use the minus operator :/ . I've been thinking about it this morning but I just can't figure this out.. Maybe i'm not just good with these bit-wise operations :((

Comment: Just because the output happens to come out right most of the time doesn't mean you don't have a problem. ;) The `x` is undefined in the expression, clearly. You don't need the minus operator just to say `return (0xFFFFFFFF << (32-n));`. No `x` is even needed. But if you're not allowed to use the `-` operator, even that's not legal in your case. Consider flipping it around as `~(0xFFFFFFFF >> n)`. But that still leaves you with the problem of C ignoring `>> 32`.

Comment: But you are using the minus operator in (32 - n) :/

Comment: I found a way to do this on another site. But I am not satisfied with using that way when I don't understand how this is done. I really want to be able to do this on my own :(

This is the code I found:
     ((!!n & 1) << 31) >> (n + (~1 + 1));

Comment: I found another way as well. The key here is to avoid the shift by `32`. So think of a way to break it into two shifts by splitting up the `n` somehow. I found a couple of ways to do that by shifting and/or adding with `n`.

Comment: You're the one who used the minus operator in `32-n` originally, so I used it, too. ;) Like I said, flip it around per my other comment to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to figure this out on your own, I'll provide some clues. This is one particular approach. There may be other equally good methods to do this.

This function will work *except* for the value of `32` as an argument:

```
int upperBits(int n) {
    return ~(0xFFFFFFFFU >> n);
}
```

This doesn't work for `n == 32` because C will ignore the shift of `32`. You can get past this by splitting the shift up into two pieces that add up to `n`. In other words:

```
return ~((0xFFFFFFFFU >> x) >> y);
```

Where `x` and `y` add up to `n`. There are some very simple ways to come up with `x` and `y` by manipulating `n` with the allowed operators. You can also do this inline and not have to declare variables `x` and `y`.

Comment: I get the idea of splitting the shift into two pieces but I somehow can't entirely wrap my head around this bit-shifting and bit-wise operators. Maybe it comes with practice :(

Comment: @drleifz if you're new to the bit manipulation, get some graph paper and draw lots of pictures of bits. It really helps! I still do that for complex cases. :) One key here to know is that in C the `<<` and `>>` operators will zero-fill for an unsigned integer. So `0xFFFFFFFFU >> 1` is `0x7FFFFFFFU`. If you are doing signed integers, then a *shift right* will *sign extend*, which means whatever the high bit (number 31 in a 32-bit number) is, will be propagated. So in that case, `0xFFFF0000 >> 1` as a signed shift becomes `0xFFFF8000` not `0x7FFF8000`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Yes I think it would really help to draw things up when thinking about bit manipulation :)